# Drupal multi-site single code base other domain name pointing

Tags: drupal, dns, point

I have a Drupal multi-site setup using a single code base.
I have a site running in /home/drupal/sites/wxyz.com
I want to point another domain name to the same site(same content). The domain is wxyz.net. 
Do I make a copy of entry for wxyz.com in the vhosts file and copy it for wxyz.net ?
Do I need a symbolic link for this also? 
I don't want an entire new site for wxyz.net, I just want the domain to point to the .com.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If both sites share the same content you don't need to do anything but set up the vhost. If you have different content you will need 2 different settings.php files.

You should not need to set up a symlink in either setup.

Comment: I tried that. My main site setup in Drupal is site.mydomain.com. I copied the vhost entry and changed only the domain name to  site1.mydomain.com. When I go to site1.mydomain.com in the browser, Drupal is asking me to do an install.

Comment: what is your settings.php file named? settings.php or mydomain.settings.php? For this to work it needs to be named settings.php

Comment: Oh sorry, move the settings file to /sites/default/settings.php

Comment: I don't want to setup another site though. I found it easier to just do a redirect in the .htaccess file.
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^drupaltest1\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://drupal.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]